# How to create an exe for a web application?

Tags: asp.net, web-applications, exe

I had developed a web application using Visual studio 2012 (ASP.Net 4.5 - C#) and a web service. Both are laying in a single solution. I need to convert my solution to an EXE file (Creating EXE for my web application). What i need exactly is, if run my setup file, it should host my web application and web service in IIS. Kindly provide the steps to solve me the problem.

Comment: Your question is really unclear. You have built a web-application, but you want to distribute it as an executable file? This isn't really possible, but you could do something like distribute it with a compatible web-server, such as IISExpress. Please can you clarify your requirements though, because they make little sense at the moment.

Comment: @RB. Am having a web application and a web service under a single solution file. Now we need different ports and virtual directories to access these application and service. To avoid it, i need to create a single EXE, that should contain my application and service.

Comment: You state you want different ports and virtual directories for accessing your application/services. I don't understand what relevance an `*.exe` file is to this issue. Please edit your question to **fully** explain your problem, and **why** you think making your application launchable from an EXE will fix this.

Comment: @RB. Thanks for your reply I edited my question now. I created a setup file using "InstallShield" (Its a 3rd party tool). Now am running the setup, it is opening in Visual studio screen instead of running in browser.

Comment: @RB. While i am installing this setup, it shows a warning "This setup was created with an EVALUATION VERSION of InstallShield". Finally my requirement is, application should hosted in IIS while i am running the setup

Answer (score 2):

Quiet a late answer:
I cannot post the whole project here but i'll post the **flow chart** here and you may try it.

All the steps in the flowchart here should be controlled programmatically.

***1. Steps in starting the application.***

[image]

NOTE: Please ignore the third layer (Is website added) if you are using a local database(.mdf)

The connection string to be used for a local database:

```
public string ConnectionString =
            "Data Source=(local);Initial Catalog=YOUR_DATABASE_NAME;Integrated Security=True";
```

But still remember that you need dotnet framework to be installed inorder to run your application. don't worry as you can set the pre-requisites in your application setup project.

All the codes for the flowchart process below.

**Is IIS Installed**:

> NOTE: I am posting the code for IIS 7 and above.

```
public bool IsIISInstalled()
        {
            return Registry.GetValue(@"HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\InetStp",
                "VersionString", null) != null;
        }
```

**Install IIS**

```
public int InstallIIS()
        {
            string DISM_CMD_CODE = "START /WAIT DISM /Online /Enable-Feature /FeatureName:IIS-ApplicationDevelopment /FeatureName:IIS-ASP /FeatureName:IIS-ASPNET /FeatureName:IIS-BasicAuthentication /FeatureName:IIS-CGI /FeatureName:IIS-ClientCertificateMappingAuthentication /FeatureName:IIS-CommonHttpFeatures /FeatureName:IIS-CustomLogging /FeatureName:IIS-DefaultDocument /FeatureName:IIS-DigestAuthentication /FeatureName:IIS-DirectoryBrowsing /FeatureName:IIS-FTPExtensibility /FeatureName:IIS-FTPServer /FeatureName:IIS-FTPSvc /FeatureName:IIS-HealthAndDiagnostics /FeatureName:IIS-HostableWebCore /FeatureName:IIS-HttpCompressionDynamic /FeatureName:IIS-HttpCompressionStatic /FeatureName:IIS-HttpErrors /FeatureName:IIS-HttpLogging /FeatureName:IIS-HttpRedirect /FeatureName:IIS-HttpTracing /FeatureName:IIS-IIS6ManagementCompatibility /FeatureName:IIS-IISCertificateMappingAuthentication /FeatureName:IIS-IPSecurity /FeatureName:IIS-ISAPIExtensions /FeatureName:IIS-ISAPIFilter /FeatureName:IIS-LegacyScripts /FeatureName:IIS-LegacySnapIn /FeatureName:IIS-LoggingLibraries /FeatureName:IIS-ManagementConsole /FeatureName:IIS-ManagementScriptingTools /FeatureName:IIS-ManagementService /FeatureName:IIS-Metabase /FeatureName:IIS-NetFxExtensibility /FeatureName:IIS-ODBCLogging /FeatureName:IIS-Performance /FeatureName:IIS-RequestFiltering /FeatureName:IIS-RequestMonitor /FeatureName:IIS-Security /FeatureName:IIS-ServerSideIncludes /FeatureName:IIS-StaticContent /FeatureName:IIS-URLAuthorization /FeatureName:IIS-WebDAV /FeatureName:IIS-WebServer /FeatureName:IIS-WebServerManagementTools /FeatureName:IIS-WebServerRole /FeatureName:IIS-WindowsAuthentication /FeatureName:IIS-WMICompatibility /FeatureName:WAS-ConfigurationAPI /FeatureName:WAS-NetFxEnvironment /FeatureName:WAS-ProcessModel /FeatureName:WAS-WindowsActivationService";
            string command = DISM_CMD_CODE;
            ProcessStartInfo pStartInfo = new ProcessStartInfo("cmd.exe", "/c " + command);
            Process p = new Process();
            p.StartInfo = pStartInfo;
            //p.WaitForExit();
            p.Start();
            return 1;
        }
```

**Is Website added**

```
public bool IsWebsiteAddedInIIS(string WebsiteName)
        {
            ServerManager serverManager = new ServerManager();
            var site = serverManager.Sites.FirstOrDefault(s => s.Name == WebsiteName);
            if (site == null)
            {
                //No site added
                return false;
            }
            else
            {
                //site added
                return true;
            }
        }

public int CreateNewWebsite(string SiteName, string PublishedFilesPath)
        {
            ServerManager serverManager = new ServerManager();
            var site = serverManager.Sites.FirstOrDefault(s => s.Name == SiteName);
            if (site == null)
            {
                serverManager.Sites.Add(SiteName, "http", "*:8080:", PublishedFilesPath);
                serverManager.CommitChanges();
                return 1;
            }
            else
            {
                return 2;
            }
        }

public void StartWebsite(string SiteName)
        {
            ServerManager serverManager = new ServerManager();
            var site = serverManager.Sites.FirstOrDefault(s => s.Name == SiteName);
            if (site != null)
            {
                site.Stop();
                site.Start();
            }
        }

        public void StopWebsite(string SiteName)
        {
            ServerManager serverManager = new ServerManager();
            var site = serverManager.Sites.FirstOrDefault(s => s.Name == SiteName);
            if (site != null)
            {
                site.Stop();
            }
        }
```

**Get website URL**

```
public string GetWebsiteURL(string SiteName)
        {
            //string SiteUrl = "";
            //ServerManager serverManager = new ServerManager();
            //var site = serverManager.Sites.FirstOrDefault(s => s.Name == SiteName);
            //var siteBindings = site.GetCollection("bindings");
            //string protocol = (string)siteBindings["protocol"];
            //string bindingInfo = (string)siteBindings["bindingInformation"];
            //if (protocol.StartsWith("http", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase))
            //{
            //    string[] parts = bindingInfo.Split(':');
            //    if (parts.Length == 3)
            //    {
            //        //Get the port in use HERE !!!
            //        string port = parts[1];
            //        SiteUrl = "localhost:" + port;
            //    }
            //}
            //return SiteUrl;

            int port = 0;
            string SiteUrl = "";
            ServerManager serverManager = new ServerManager();
            var site = serverManager.Sites.FirstOrDefault(s => s.Name == SiteName);
            foreach (Binding binding in site.Bindings)
            {
                port = binding.EndPoint.Port;
                SiteUrl = "localhost:" + port + "/index.aspx";
                break;
            }
            return SiteUrl;
        }
```

**Init Browsing the website**

> You have to install Cefsharp chromium browser to your windows forms

**Install-Package CefSharp.WinForms -Version 75.1.143**

```
public void InitBrowser(string Address)
        {
            Cef.Initialize(new CefSettings());
            browser = new ChromiumWebBrowser(Address);
            Controls.Add(browser);
            browser.Dock = DockStyle.Fill;
        }
```

Thank you..

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you need to create a web setup project. "A Web setup project provides the
highest level of flexibility for deploying a website. Although Web Setup Projects are more
complex for the developer, they allow you to generate an MSI package, precompile a website,
and perform virtually any setup task that your application might require.

Many websites do not require custom configuration. In these cases, you can simply build
your MSI file and be ready to deploy. However, more complex scenarios include dependencies
(such as particular operating system versions or service packs), custom registry entries,
or administrator configuration. Web Setup Projects allow you to deploy websites that meet
these requirements."

Check the book "MCTS Self-Paced Training Kit (Exam 70-515) - Web Applications Development with Microsoft .NET Framework 4" at the chapter 8 "Debugging and deploying".

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks for your reply I edited my question now. I created a setup file using "InstallShield" (Its a 3rd party tool). While i am installing this setup, it shows a warning "This setup was created with an EVALUATION VERSION of InstallShield". Finally my requirement is, application should hosted in IIS while i am running the setup. Kindly help me in solving this issue.