# Converting ASP Website in EXE setup with SQL Server database file

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, web-applications

I have created a web application using ASP.NET and C#. How can I convert my whole application with its database files to an EXE setup file to make it running as a desktop application?

Comment: I recommend you re-write the app in to EXE using Windows Application project or WPF application. You cannot just convert.

Comment: ASP.NET is a **web framework** - it cannot be *converted* to be a desktop application (short of **rewriting** the whole code)

Comment: WPF, UWP probably Winforms too?

Comment: [For converting your asp.net web application to exe using cefsharp and a little c# code](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59113401/9048996)

Answer (score 0):

I think you can use 'Owin' to holding your website, 'Owin' is a solution for shelfhost, and it can make website startup by an exe application. Something demo in github [enter link description here](https://github.com/beginor/static-file-middleware-demo)